# How to access a Redshift DB through VPN to extract data and load into own Azure environment?

Tags: azure, amazon-redshift, azure-data-factory, vpn

pretty new to the Azure environment and so far my search for information wasnt very successful.

Problem is as follows:

- we wanna access a redshift DB which you can only connect to if you are conntected to a specific VPN beforehand - this is the main problem
- we then wanna build an automated data pipeline which extracts daily updated data from the redshift db and create our own analytics solution from it
- how can that be set up in a fully automated workflow and also in the simplest, most efficient way with the tools available on the azure platform?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If VPN is not the challenge and you just need to extract the data from Redshift DB and store it in any Azure Service like Blob Storage or Azure Synapse Analytics, then best possible way is to use Azure Data Factory. Azure Data Factory is a fully managed, serverless data integration service.

You can copy data using `Copy activity` from Amazon Redshift to any supported sink data store. For a list of data stores that are supported as sources/sinks by the copy activity, see the [Supported data stores table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats).

Specifically, this Amazon Redshift connector supports retrieving data from Redshift using query or built-in Redshift UNLOAD support.

**Note:** When copying data to an Azure data store, see [Azure Data Center IP Ranges](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) for the Compute IP address and SQL ranges used by the Azure data centers.

In case you need to import data into Azure SQL database from AWS Redshift, follow the [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/import-data-into-azure-sql-database-from-aws-redshift/).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. Indeed establishing the VPN is the main problem. We know that Data Factory is the best tool to build the ETL pipeline but dont know how to integrate the VPN connection into the workflow.

Comment: yes, I'm not sure VPN establishment is even feasible in ADF, but it has inbuilt security consideration which make the data integration secure. refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-movement-security-considerations